# How to emulate styled HTML meter with two linear-gradient backgrounds, while avoiding the gradients horizontally compressing?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

It seems to be damn-near impossible to style a `<meter>` HTML element to any interesting degree, so I am emulating a meter using CSS.

I have a step-wise gray linear gradient I want to use for the "unfilled" right-hand portion of the meter
[image: gray step gradient]

```css
background-image: linear-gradient(
  to right,
  #ddd 20%,
  #ccc 20%,
  #ccc 40%,
  #bbb 40%,
  #bbb 60%,
  #aaa 60%,
  #aaa 80%,
  #999 80%,
  #999 100%
);
```

and a step-wise green-ish gradient I want to use for the "filled" left-hand portion of the meter.
[image: green step gradient]

```
background-image: linear-gradient(
  to right,
  #70f600 20%,
  #0e0 20%,
  #0e0 40%,
  #0d0 40%,
  #0d0 60%,
  #0c0 60%,
  #0c0 80%,
  #0b0 80%,
  #0b0 100%
);
```

**The effect I want** is that

- at 0% full meter, the styled meter will be the gray step gradient alone;
- at 100% full meter, the styled meter will be the green step gradient alone;
- at some intermediate percent (0% < X < 100%) full meter, the leftmost X% of the styled meter will be the leftmost X% of the green step gradient, and the remaining rightmost space of the styled meter will be the corresponding rightmost space of the gray step gradient. For example:

  - at ~36% fill
    [image: green and gray step gradient 36%]
  - at ~82% fill
    [image: green and gray step gradient 82%]
- crucially, neither step gradient should be horizontally compressed to fit into the available space.

This last bulletpoint is what I am struggling to achieve.

My current best effort is the following HTML and CSS (to produce, in this case, a 36% filled meter):

HTML

```html
<div class="meter-gauge">
  <div class="negative-space" style="width: calc(100% - 36%)"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.meter-gauge {
  position: relative;

  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  min-width: 10em;

  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #70f600 20%,
    #0e0 20%,
    #0e0 40%,
    #0d0 40%,
    #0d0 60%,
    #0c0 60%,
    #0c0 80%,
    #0b0 80%,
    #0b0 100%
  );
}

.negative-space {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  
  height: inherit;
  width: 0; /* Overridden by style attribute */

  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #ddd 20%,
    #ccc 20%,
    #ccc 40%,
    #bbb 40%,
    #bbb 60%,
    #aaa 60%,
    #aaa 80%,
    #999 80%,
    #999 100%
  );
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Here, unlike the desired meter styling, displayed earlier, we get a version where the gray step gradient is horizontally compressed to fit 100% of the gradient into 64% of the space.
[image: green and gray step gradient 36% incorrect]

For comparison, an 82% filled meter with the above CSS looks like this, where the issue is even more obvious:
[image: green and gray step gradient 82% incorrect]

**How can I achieve the look I want**, and avoid one of the two gradients being included in its entirety but horizontally squashed into the available space?

I have noted that the effect I want would have been possible to achieve if the two gradients were instead two image files, as demonstrated by this [image comparison slider demo](https://codyhouse.co/demo/image-comparison-slider/index.html). This seems to be because the image files are defined with absolute widths, and are then scaled as necessary. The gradients on the other hand are defined only using percentages, which relate only to the width of the containing block, not that block's parent block width.

Note: I don't want to use absolute CSS size units, as I want to be able to plug this styled meter in anywhere, at any size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `clip-path`?

#### Example code

```css
.gauge {
  width: 30em;
  height: 2em;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.gauge > * {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.meter-gauge {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right,
      #70f600 20%,
      #0e0 20%,
      #0e0 40%,
      #0d0 40%,
      #0d0 60%,
      #0c0 60%,
      #0c0 80%,
      #0b0 80%,
      #0b0 100%);  
}

.negative-space {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right,
      #ddd 20%,
      #ccc 20%,
      #ccc 40%,
      #bbb 40%,
      #bbb 60%,
      #aaa 60%,
      #aaa 80%,
      #999 80%,
      #999 100%);
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 30%);
}
```

```html
<div class="gauge">
  <div class="meter-gauge"></div>
  <div class="negative-space"></div>  
</div>
```

#### How it works

```css
clip-path: inset(top right bottom left)
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! This works perfectly! I didn't know about clip-path, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just have a couple of elements, or pseudo elements, with the green on top of the gray.

Green one has clip-path:

```
clip-path: polygon(0 0, var(—pc) 0, var(—pc) 100%, 0 100%);
```

Where —pc is percentage required e.g 36%

Sorry I can’t give a proper snippet as am stuck on an iOS device.

Comment: clip-path was the answer, thank you! I marked Miu's answer as the accepted one, as it was a bit more elaborate, but yours was also sufficient for me to solve the issue.